# phyton3 pip and pyautogui install mac -remove broken python

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, installation, pyautogui

having jumped into java development a year ago, i now struggle myself thru terminal commands and try to get the red line in it.

I now want to set up python3 and pyautogui following this tutorial:
https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter18/

unfortunately I keep failing setting up the needed module:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-ct_f0rph/pyobjc-core
```

if you please could help me out removing old python installations, and linking python command to python3 i´d be very happy :)

thanks a lot!

EDIT:
my problem was due to missing xcode, installing it and agreeing license made it work with below answer

still had a problem after installing pip, here is the solve for all who still get problems:

download recommended file and run the setup inside, had to punch in many commands to run it from appropiate  directory but it finally works when importing pyautogui:

https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/related/3z5h0b/trouble_importing_pyautogui_os_x/

ps: i only downloaded the tar ball and used the setup.py inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download proper installer of python 3:
[Python3](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.1/python-3.5.1-macosx10.6.pkg)

Install `Xcode` (get it from [Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/xcode)) if you don't have it yet.

Point `xcode-select` to the `Xcode Developer` directory using the following command:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Open command line and navigate to `python3` directory:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin
```

Run:

```
sudo pip3 install pyobjc-framework-Quartz
sudo pip3 install pyobjc-core
sudo pip3 install pyobjc
pip3 install pyautogui
```

Try your installation from the command line, type:

```
python3
import pyautogui
```

If everything is fine you won't have an import error.
I hope it helps.