# pyautogui and Mac OSX: is xcode necessary?

Tags: python, xcode, macos, python-3.x, pyautogui

When trying to install pyautogui I received the following error message:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-dq2l07no/pyobjc-core
```

This exact problem is discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35051580/phyton3-pip-and-pyautogui-install-mac-remove-broken-python) were installing xcode seems to fix it but it's a rather large file. is it absolutely necessary to install Xcode? is there a workaround?

thanks

Comment: If it looks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck, then it probably is a duck.

Answer (score 1):

According to the installation instructions here https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html you must first run:

```
pip3 install pyobjc-core
pip3 install pyobjc
```

...before you can run `pip3 install pyautogui`. (Or use pip instead of pip3 if you are installing for Python 2.)